# jQuery: Chaining Events - code correction

Tags: jquery, events, chaining

Can any one tell me how can i replace the slideup function with fadeout('slow') for the below code

```
 div.slideUp(function() {        
        div.load("GetResults.aspx?mode=bymanu&mid="+manuId,
                         { symbol: $("#txtSymbol" ).val() },
                           function() {
                           $(this).slideDown();                               
                       });
```

Instead of slideUp,I want to use the FadeOut function with a speed .How can i chain up the events ?

I want to replace the SlideDown also with FadeIn('slow')

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn) are actually a really good place to check for syntax like this.

```
div.fadeOut('slow', function() {        
    div.load(
        "GetResults.aspx?mode=bymanu&mid="+manuId,
        { symbol: $("#txtSymbol" ).val() },
        function() {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');                               
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks nickF .What does this symbol: $("#txtSymbol" ).val()  actually do here ?

Comment: It finds an object with id="textSymbol". It seems you're pretty new to jQuery since this is the basic building blocks of the toolkit, so I'd recommend taking a look at some tutorials: http://webtecker.com/2008/06/02/beginner-jquery-tutorials/

Comment: er.. that should be "txtSymbol"

Answer (score 0):

[SelectorGadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) works really.  It allows you to evolve your selection choice with each mouse click on the page sections.  You load via a shortcut like so:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20s=document.createElement('div');s.innerHTML='Loading...';s.style.color='black';s.style.padding='20px';s.style.position='fixed';s.style.zIndex='9999';s.style.fontSize='3.0em';s.style.border='2px%20solid%20black';s.style.right='40px';s.style.top='40px';s.setAttribute('class','selector_gadget_loading');s.style.background='white';document.body.appendChild(s);s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');s.setAttribute('src','http://www.selectorgadget.com/unstable/lib/selectorgadget_edge.js?raw=true');document.body.appendChild(s);})();
```

The site has a great demo.